# HandlerSocket transactions

Tags: mysql, transactions, nosql, redis

In Redis can complete the transaction in this way:

```
redis.watch('powerlevel')
current = redis.get('powerlevel')
redis.multi()
redis.set('powerlevel', current + 1)
redis.exec()
```

1. Is it possible to perform this operation using the HandlerSocket?
2. What are the general features for working with transaction provides handlersotsket?

Comment: More info about Redis transactions [here](https://github.com/kondratovich/the-little-redis-book/blob/master/en/redis.md), see chapter transactions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing Redis "transactions" to a general purpose transactional engine is always a bit misleading. A Redis WATCH/MULTI/EXEC block is:

- Not atomic (no rollback in case of error)
- Consistent (there are not many consistency rules anyway with Redis)
- Fully isolated (everything is serialized)
- Possibly durable if AOF+fsync strategy is selected

So the full ACID properties which are commonly used to define a transaction are not completely provided by Redis. Contrary to most transactional engines, Redis provides very strong isolation, and does not attempt to provide any rollback capabilities.

The example provided in the question is not really representative IMO, since the same behavior can be achieved in a simpler way by just using:

redis.incr( "powerlevel" )

because Redis **single** operations are always atomic and isolated.

WATCH/MULTI/EXEC blocks are typically used when consistency between various keys must be enforced, or to implement optimistic locking patterns. In other words, if your purpose is just to increment isolated counters, there is no need to use a WATCH/MULTI/EXEC block.

The HandlerSocket is a complete different beast. It is built on top of the generic handler of MySQL, and depending on the underlying storage engine, the transactional behavior will be different. For instance when it is used with MyISAM, it will use no ACID transactions, but consistency will be ensured by a R/W lock at the table level. With InnoDB, ACID transactions will be used with the default isolation level (which can be set in the InnoDB configuration AFAIK). InnoDB implements MVCC (multi-versioning concurrency control), so locking is much more complex than with MyISAM.

The HandlerSocket works with two pools of worker threads (one for read-only connections, one for write oriented connections). People are supposed to use several read worker threads, but only one write thread though (probably to decrease locking contention). So in the base configuration, write operations are serialized, but not read operations. AFAIK, the only possibility to have the same isolation semantic than Redis is to only use the write oriented socket to perform both read and write operations, and keep only one write thread (full serialization of all operations). It will impact scalability though.

From the HandlerSocket protocol, there is no access to transactional capabilities. At each event loop iteration, it collects all the operations (coming from all the sockets), and perform a unique transaction (only relevant with InnoDB) for all these operations. AFAIK, the user has no way to alter the scope of this transaction.

The conclusion is it is not generally possible to emulate the behavior of a Redis WATCH/MULTI/EXEC block with HandlerSocket.

Now, back to the example, if the purpose is just to increment counters in a consistent way, this is fully supported by [the HandlerSocket protocol](https://github.com/DeNADev/HandlerSocket-Plugin-for-MySQL/blob/master/docs-en/protocol.en.txt). For instance, the +/- (increment/decrement) operations are available, and also the U? operation (similar to Redis GETSET command), or +?/-? (increment/decrement, returning the previous value).

Comment: Thank you, I have come to the same conclusion regarding the use of U? and +?,-? operations.